# Finding an employee from a given mother company

Tags: javascript

This method finds an employee from a given mother company which consists of group of companies. An employee can work for many child company.

```
$scope.getEmployee = function(subsidiary, salaryScale){ //1
  var workingDepartments = [];//2
  var findInGroupOfCompanies =  function(comGroup, salaryScale){//3
                                 var salaryIndex = subsidiary[salaryScale];//4
                                 if(salaryIndex != "SUPERIOR" && salaryIndex == comGroup.salaryIndex) {//5
                                     if(comGroup.hasSubsidiaries()) { //6
                                        findInGroupOfCompanies(comGroup, salaryScale++ ); //7
                                     } else {//8
                                        workingDepartments.push(comGroup);//8
                                       //and do some stuff
                                     }
                                 }
};
```

The method `findInGroupOfCompanies` and its function is separated by equal and intended. Is this formatting not adhering to general code styles in JS? Have I added spaces unnecessarily after line number 3?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As we all are concerned with various aspects of our code, titles on Code Review are recommended to be about what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. You are free to get answers about your indentation but other users might also notice other aspects of your code and may answer about those. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/31562) for guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, style considerations are subject to opinion and your actual style usually doesn't matter as much as being consistent. That said, your code might be found more readable if formatted like so:

```
$scope.getEmployee = function(subsidiary, salaryScale) { //1
    var workingDepartments = []; //2
    var findInGroupOfCompanies = function(comGroup, salaryScale) { //3
        var salaryIndex = subsidiary[salaryScale]; //4
        if (salaryIndex != "SUPERIOR" && salaryIndex == comGroup.salaryIndex) { //5
            if (comGroup.hasSubsidiaries()) { //6
                findInGroupOfCompanies(comGroup, salaryScale++); //7
            } else { //8
                workingDepartments.push(comGroup); //8
                //and do some stuff
            }
        }
    };
```

It's not necessary to indent `findInGroupOfCompanies` all the way to align with the equals sign. One additional level of indentation is sufficient to indicate a new block, and anybody reading the code can see that it's a new function declaration.